# Why don't we use iron wheel also in our cars, while our trains have well working iron wheels?

Tags: friction

Why don't we use iron wheel in the cars instead of rubber? We use iron wheel in trains, which works.

What is the physical reason, what makes iron wheels disadvantegous in cars?

Comment: noise level     , think what a city would sound like. I suppose also safety, iron slides much more than tires

Comment: If iron slide more then we use rubber tyre in train

Comment: the road of the train is iron too. On tarmak the train shape iron wheel would destroy the tarmak,

Comment: Welcome on PSE :) Please consider extending your question, outlining your thoughts and your ideas about the relevant physical effects - this way, answers are more likely to come and be of high quality.

Answer (score 6):

[You'd do well to watch this video; James may does a better job explaining it than I can.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbUsKWbOqUU)

I'll still try to explain. Trains use steel/iron wheels to reduce friction and drag, thus increasing their efficiency. The problem is that the same slippery steel-on-steel contact that makes them great for long-distance travel also makes them terrible at stopping and climbing hills.

Cars, on the other hand, operate under completely different circumstances. Since they don't have tracks to guide them, they need very grippy high-friction tires to stick to the road. Rubber is a good candidate for this, and also provides an incidental benefit of cushioning lightly impacts from bumps.

Side note: Have you ever seen a car driving on its rims? The sparks it makes are unholy and the friction tears the rim apart in short order. Steel-on-concrete is bad for steel.